# Maven doesn't find JUnit test to run

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, junit

When I try to run my tests with maven (`mvn test`), it seems that maven doen't find any test to run:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running calculator.CalculatorTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944095/maven-doesnt-find-tests), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833127/no-test-run-when-running-maven-test-command), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566240/mvn-test-not-finding-junit-tests) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178583/maven-does-not-find-junit-tests-to-run) questions, but it doesn't solve my problem.

I have a simple Java project using Maven and JUnit. My project structure is the following:

```
\_ src
  \_ main
     \_ java
        \_ calculator
           \_ Calculator.java
  \_ test
     \_ java
        \_ calculator
           \_ CalculatorTest.java
```

In my CalculatorTest.java file, I have this:

```java
    package calculator;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

    public class CalculatorTest {

        @Test
        public void addABPositive() {
            Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
            int a, b, res;
            a = 5;
            b = 5;
            res = a + b;
            if (calculator.add(a, b) != res) {
                fail("a and b positive");
            }
        }
    }
```

My `pom.xml` file is (auto-generated by IntelliJ):

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>HelloWorld</groupId>
        <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
    </project>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe the dependencies, wrong version of JUnit ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: `@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` or `@org.junit.Test`?

Comment: Well, `alt+enter` in IntelliJ automatically added `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`. So I guess it's that

Comment: BTW: I hope you have your `*.java` files in `src/test/java` and `src/test/java` and not `*.class` files?

Comment: Yes of course, It's `.java`. it's a typo I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are several issues. First compiler source/target 1.6 does not work cause Junit 5 needs JDK 8 minimum...

To run JUnit 5 tests you have to add the following dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    [...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    [...]
</dependencies>
```

Second as already mentioned you need to pin maven-surefire-plugin to minimum 2.22.1...

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example project provided by the junit-team on [github](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.4.0/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml) , the pom requires the surefire plugin to be configured:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- JUnit 5 requires Surefire version 2.22.1 or higher -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, also adding the dependency mentionned by  @khmarbaise

Comment: hm, but maven-surefire-plugin is just a test report plugin. How can it help you to fix the issue?